# Parabolic theory for singular coefficients on bounded domains (Reference Request)

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, linear-pde, regularity

In [Evans](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821849743), the theory for linear PDE of parabolic type with bounded coefficients is developed. There are nice results such as long-existence of weak solutions and the parabolic regularity theorems.

Is there any development of such theory for linear operators of parabolic type, which have singular coefficients?

For a simple example take a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $0\in \Omega$, or maybe even just $\Omega=(0,a)$, for some $a>0$. Is there existence and regularity theory that could be applied to an equation of the form

$$
\partial_t u =\partial^2_{x}u+\cot(x)\partial_xu+u
$$
defined on $[0,T] \times\Omega$ under some appropriate boundary conditions? What about if $\Omega \subset\mathbb{R}^n$?

Is there any book I could consult that would give an exposition of these results? I have seen specific results in papers but they are not as unified or general as the treatment given by Evans in the case of bounded coefficients.